# how to get codeigniter url parameters in jquery ajax function

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, jquery, query-string

I have the following url in codeigniter.

```
<a href="../add-item-to-wishlist/5/21" class="wishlist_item">Add to wishlist</a>
```

and I have the following jquery function

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('body').on('click', 'a.wishlist_item', function(e){
            $.ajax({
            url:"../add-item-to-wishlist",
            data : "the query string",
                success: function(result){
                    // success code.
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
          });
        });
    </script>
```

how do I get the query string value and pass to the above url ? the add-to-wishlist route redirect to a controller function which take exactly two parameters.

```
function add_to_wishlist($itemID,$wishlistID = NULL)
```

What I want to do is call this function using ajax but I dont know how do I call this using ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your anchor URL to the controller method

```
href = "add_to_wishlist/5/21"
```

Then you can do a `get` request with the full URL

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('body').on('click', 'a.wishlist_item', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var obj = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type:'get',
            url:obj.attr('href'),
            success: function(result){
                // success code.
            }
        });

      });
    });
</script>
```